# Accessing a public mapping from a deployed Ethereum Contract

Tags: solidity, truffle, contract-deployment

I'm trying to get my Contract to interface with the already-deployed **CryptoPunksMarket** Contract, seen here:

https://etherscan.io/address/0xb47e3cd837ddf8e4c57f05d70ab865de6e193bbb#code

Specifically, I only need to access the `punkIndexToAddress` `public mapping` which that contract declares, as follows:

```
mapping (uint => address) public punkIndexToAddress;
```

My own Solidity contract references this **CryptoPunksMarket** contract as follows:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.1 <0.8.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

import "./MarketLib.sol";
import "./MyERC721.sol";


// Step one:  I declare the already-deployed "CryptoPunksMarket" contract 
contract CryptoPunksMarket {
    mapping (uint => address) public punkIndexToAddress;
}
```

My understanding is that you don't have to declare the ENTIRE contract you're trying to interface with, but only the specific methods you're interested in - which is why I only declare the `punkIndexToAddress` mapping.

Next is my contract:

```
contract MyMarketplace is MyERC721 {

   using MarketLib for MarketLib.PunkCell;

   // Here's the reference to the "CryptoPunksMarket" using it's deployed Ethereum address:
   CryptoPunksMarket punksContract = CryptoPunksMarket(0xb47e3cd837dDF8e4c57F05d70Ab865de6e193BBB);

   address public punk9999OwnerAddress;


   constructor() MyERC721() public { 

      // Trying to access the "punkIndexToAddress" public mapping from that contract:
      punk9999OwnerAddress = punksContract.punkIndexToAddress(9999);

      // etc.
   }
}
```

Here's what happens when I try to deploy this using `localhost` with `Truffle`:

```
Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"MyMarketplace" hit a require or revert statement somewhere in its constructor. Try:
   * Verifying that your constructor params satisfy all require conditions.
   * Adding reason strings to your require statements.
```

Since I have no idea why this is happening, I tried moving the code out of the `Constructor` into its own separate function, just to see if that would make a difference - or at least give me a different wording for the Error when it crashes.

So I did this:

```
function getOwnerOfPunkNumber() public returns (address ownerOfPunk) {
    return punksContract.punkIndexToAddress(9999);
}
```

Using `truffle`, I tried calling that function - here's the result of that:

```
truffle(development)> myContract.getOwnerOfPunkNumber()
Uncaught Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:0:12
    at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:272:15)
    at Script.runInContext (vm.js:139:14)
    at runScript (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/console.js:251:1)
    at Console.interpret (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/console.js:266:1)
    at bound (domain.js:430:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:443:12)
    at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:817:10)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at REPLServer.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:486:12)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:337:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:666:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:1010:14)
    at REPLServer.self._ttyWrite (repl.js:907:9)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:213:10)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:486:12)
    at emitKeys (internal/readline/utils.js:345:14)
    at emitKeys.next (<anonymous>)
    at ReadStream.onData (readline.js:1144:36)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:486:12)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:9)
    at ReadStream.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:223:10)
```

etc.

So what am I doing wrong here?
Does this have to do with different Solidity Compiler versions? Or the fact that my contract uses `pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2`?

I feel like that first error I got - when the code was in the `Constructor` - is really telling, but I have no idea what it might be referring to, since I have no `require` or `revert` statements in my `constructor`:

```
"MyMarketplace" hit a require or revert statement somewhere in its constructor. Try:
   * Verifying that your constructor params satisfy all require conditions.
   * Adding reason strings to your require statements.
```

Any ideas what might be happening here?

Comment: I don't why it fails, perhaps is due to `pragma experimental` since CryptoPunk uses solc 0.4.18. You can try declaring it as a getter `function punkIndexToAddress(uint256) external view returns (address)`.